# About skia antialias

Tags: antialiasing, skia

Recently I'm learning skia library(google open source 2d engine,be used on Android and chromium,etc.),Now I want to use it on windows instead of GDI+ dont support clip area with antialias,during it, I find a problem about pixel.

[up is set antialias,down is not set antialias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVhH2.jpg)

the main code is:

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
paint.setStyle(SkPaint::kStroke_Style);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawRect(skrect,paint);  //draw up rect

skrect.fTop += 110;
skrect.fBottom += 110;

paint.setAntiAlias(false);
canvas.drawRect(skrect, paint); //draw down rect
```

As you see,the same rect,if I not set Antialias,the boundary pixel is 1(I set strock width is 1),but if I set Antialias, the boundary pixel is 2,and it become a bit light,although I set color is black.

I dont konw why,anyone can tell me?

thk,

Answer (score 1):

This happens because OpenGL assumes that each pixel is centered at [0.5; 0.5]. The rasterizer have to draw indeed two pixels and interpolate the alpha. [Read more here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20gl_FragCoord%20assumes%20a%20lower%2Dleft%20origin%20for%20window%20coordinates%20and%20assumes%20pixel%20centers%20are%20located%20at%20half%2Dpixel%20centers.%20For%20example%2C%20the%20(x%2C%20y)%20location%20(0.5%2C%200.5)%20is%20returned%20for%20the%20lower%2Dleft%2Dmost%20pixel%20in%20a%20window.%20lower-left-most%20pixel%20in%20a%20window.)

If you would like to draw sharp 1px lines with antialiasing turned on just offset coordinates of a line or other figure with 0.5f.

For example a point at [10; 10] should have coordinates [10.5; 10.5] and so on

Answer (score 0):

now,maybe I konw.

the skia library canvas should be like Html5`s canvas ,Canvas every line have an infinite thin "line", the width of the line from the center line to stretch,so if we draw a 1px line,in fact,it will fill two of 0.5 pixel point,but the display device dont allow it do that,so it will fill 2 pixel point,and set it color more light to differentiate real 2 pixels .

I will search more material to prove it.